# Selecting an algorithm and key for Java Card encryption

Tags: java, cryptography, embedded

I was playing around with Java Card and I try to do one of the examples.

P1 is what it has to do (e.g. decrypt, encrypt, etc) and P2 is to select which key to use in P1. Here is what the code looks like - well, half of it anyway, since I'm not really used to formatting in this site and it takes awhile to copy the code and make it pretty.

So my question here is, how can I simplify this nested switch? Or maybe I don't need to use nested switch at all?

```
switch (buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1]){
    case (byte) 0x01:
        switch (buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2]){
            case (byte) 0x01:
                doSingleDES(apdu, DESKey1);
                return;
            case (byte) 0x02:
                doSingleDES(apdu, DESKey2);
                return;
            case (byte) 0x03:
                doSingleDES(apdu, DESKey3);
                return;
            case (byte) 0x04:
                doSingleDES(apdu, DESKey3);
                return;
            default:
                ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_WRONG_P1P2);
        }return;
    case (byte) 0x02:
        switch (buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2]){
            case (byte) 0x01:
                doEncrypt(apdu, DESKey1);
                return;
            case (byte) 0x02:
                doEncrypt(apdu, DESKey2);
                return;
            case (byte) 0x03:
                doEncrypt(apdu, DESKey3);
                return;
            case (byte) 0x04:
                doEncrypt(apdu, DESKey4);
                return;
            default:
                ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INCORRECT_P1P2);
    }return;
    default:
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INCORRECT_P1P2);
```

Comment: Since it looks like your code is working, I'm going to send you in the direction of the friendly folks at [codereview.se].

Comment: I don't know very much about Java Card, but what is the difference between `SW_WRONG_P1P2` (thrown in first inner `switch`) and `SW_INCORRECT_P1P2` (thrown in default and second inner `switch`)?

Comment: That's what I thought too when I saw them in the auto-completion list. I just try them both to see the difference. `SW_WRONG_P1P2` return "Wrong parameter" and `SW_INCORRECT_P1P2` return "Incorrect parameter" if you enter 05 for both case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would focus on eliminating the inner `switch` statements.  You could try to eliminate the outer `switch` as well, but it's probably not worthwhile, especially for a resource-constrained environment.

```
byte[][] desKeys = new byte[][] {
    null, DESKey1, DESKey2, DESKey3, DESKey4
};

try {
    switch (buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1]) {
      case 0x01:
        doSingleDES(apdu, desKeys[buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2]]);
        return;
      case 0x02:
        doEncrypt(apdu, desKeys[buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P2]]);
        return;
      default:
        ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INCORRECT_P1P2);
    }
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException badP2) {
    ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INCORRECT_P1P2);
}
```

Comment: I try to use your code, but it gives me error because it says can't convert from byte [] to byte [][]..if I try eliminate one of the bracket, it gives me error because can't convert null to byte..if I were to add another bracket to the single bracket, the package is giving me error because of invalid type.

Comment: @Archie what is the type of `DESKey1`, `DESKey2`, etc? If its `long`, `try long[] desKeys = new long[] {0, DESKey1, DESKey2, DESKey3, DESKey4};`

Comment: @abuzittingillifirca I use byte[]..maybe it's something to do with the version of the java card I'm using?
I'm using 2.2 version btw.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following construct to switch on both P1 and P2 simultaneously:

```
switch(Util.getShort(buf, ISO7816.OFFSET_P1)) {
    case (short)0x0101:
        doSingleDES(apdu, DESKey1);
        return;
    case (short)0x0102:
        doSingleDES(apdu, DESKey2);
        return;
    case (short)0x0103:
        ...
    case (short)0x0201:
        doEncrypt(apdu, DESKey1);
        return;
        ...
    default:
        ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INCORRECT_P1P2);
        return; // not-reachable
}
```

If you insist on different SW for P1=0x01 the default case might look like this:

```
    default:
        if(buf[ISO7816.OFFSET_P1]==(byte)0x01) {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_WRONG_P1P2);
        } else {
            ISOException.throwIt(ISO7816.SW_INCORRECT_P1P2);
        }
        return; // not-reachable
```